# process descriptor pointer doesn't match current macro in Linux Kernel

Tags: linux-kernel

I am using the `esp` value of kernel stack to calculate the process descriptor pointer value. 
According to ULK book, I just need to mask 13 least significant bits of `esp` to obtain the base address of the `thread_info` structure.
My test is:

1. write a kernel module because I need to get value of kernel stack
2. In the kernel init function, get the value of kernel stack
3. use following formula to get the process descriptor pointer of the process running on the CPU: `*((unsigned int*) esp & 0xffffe000)`
4. use the current macro, print out its value.

I think the value of step3 should be same as the value of step 4.

But my experiment results shows: sometimes they are same, and sometimes they are different. Could any explain why?  Or am I missing anything?

Comment: [Kernelnewbies has a description of how `current()` works](http://kernelnewbies.org/FAQ/current) that might be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved this problem. Everything is correct expect for the size of kernel stack. My kernel use 4KB stack instead of 8KB stack. So I just need to mask low 12 bits of the ESP.
Thanks for all the suggestions and answer!

Answer (score 1):

This is because at the base of the kernel stack you will find a `struct thread_info` instance (platform dependent) and **not** a `struct task_struct`. The `current()` macro provides a pointer to the current `task_struct`.

Try the following:

```
struct thread_info *info = (struct thread_info*)(esp & 0xfffe000);
struct task_struct *my_current = info->task;
```

Now you can compare `my_current` with `current()`.

Comment: Your code is same thing as:*((unsigned int*) esp & 0xffffe000), because the first field of thread_info is task.